# Why android studio always install sdk plataform 26

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

I'm started developping to android with android studio and im targeting api 19 so i've configured all workstation to run around it

but even if i configure a project to api 19 always on every new project android studio forces me to download android sdk 26

the default generated gradle is like

```
  compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tomatedigital.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

My computer runs on ssd and i have low free space, but even if i had tons of GB free why am i forced to download something i dont want to use? is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to target the latest sdk?  New features get backported through support libraries so they will be available to applications running older versions of the os. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/